# how to force dc.js redraw its charts after additional data was added to crossfilter

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Having trouble with dc.js not redrawing charts after additional data is added to crossfilter.
Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eugene_goldberg/v6j2ujrc/24/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dc.css" media="screen" />
    <title>Dc Tutorial</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="crossfilter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dc.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ndx;

        var data = [
            {date: "12/27/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 190, http_302: 100},
            {date: "12/28/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 10, http_302: 100},
            {date: "12/31/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
            {date: "01/01/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
            {date: "01/02/2013", http_404: 1, http_200: 10, http_302: 1},
            {date: "01/03/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
            {date: "01/04/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0}
        ];

        var data2 = [
            {date: "12/29/2012", http_404: 1, http_200: 300, http_302: 200},
            {date: "12/30/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
            {date: "01/05/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
            {date: "01/06/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 200, http_302: 1},
            {date: "01/07/2013", http_404: 1, http_200: 200, http_302: 100}
        ];

        function renderChart(){
            var hitslineChart  = dc.lineChart("#chart-line-hitsperday");

            ndx = crossfilter(data);
            var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse;
            data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.date = parseDate(d.date);
                d.total= d.http_404+d.http_200+d.http_302;
                d.Year=d.date.getFullYear();
            });

            var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.date;});
            var hits = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.total;});
            var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].date;
            var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0].date;

            hitslineChart
                    .width(500).height(200)
                    .dimension(dateDim)
                    .group(hits)
                    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]))
                    .brushOn(false)
                    .yAxisLabel("Hits per day");

            var yearRingChart   = dc.pieChart("#chart-ring-year");
            var yearDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return +d.Year;});
            var year_total = yearDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.http_200+d.http_302;});

            yearRingChart
                    .width(150).height(150)
                    .dimension(yearDim)
                    .group(year_total)
                    .innerRadius(30);

            dc.renderAll();
        }

        function addData(){
            console.log('adding data2 to ndx');
            ndx.add(data2);
            dc.redrawAll();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart-ring-year"></div>
<div id="chart-line-hitsperday"></div>
<button onclick="addData()">Add Data</button>
<script>
    renderChart();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way of making this work?

Answer (score 1):

After doing some searching, came across a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/eugene_goldberg/3tf725aL/2/), which had the needed technique:

```
'option strict'
 var data = [{
    "key": "KEY-1",
    "state": "CA",
    "topics": ["Technology", "Science", "Automotive"],
    "date": new Date("10/02/2012")
}, {
    "key": "KEY-2",
    "state": "CA",
    "topics": ["Health"],
    "date": new Date("10/05/2012")
}, {
    "key": "KEY-4",
    "state": "WA",
    "topics": ["Automotive", "Science"],
    "date": new Date("10/09/2012")
}, {
    "key": "KEY-5",
    "state": "WA",
    "topics": ["Science"],
    "date": new Date("10/09/2012")
}

];

var cf = crossfilter(data);

var states = cf.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.state;
});
var stateGroup = states.group();

var pieChart = dc.pieChart("#piechart");
pieChart.height(75).width(75).dimension(states).group(stateGroup);


dc.renderAll();

setTimeout(function () {
    cf.add([{
        "key": "KEY-6",
        "state": "MD",
        "topics": ["Science"],
        "date": new Date("10/09/2012")
    }]);
    dc.redrawAll();
}, 1000);
```